# Masstransit. Handler doesn't acknowledge messages

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, message-queue, masstransit

I have publisher:

```
 static void Main()
    {
        var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseRabbitMq(r => r.ConfigureHost(new MessageUrn("rabbitmq://localhost/test123"), c => { }));
            sbc.UseJsonSerializer();
            sbc.EnableMessageTracing();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom(new MessageUrn("rabbitmq://localhost/test345"));
        });

        bus.WriteIntrospectionToConsole();
        Console.WriteLine("bus endpoint {0}", bus.Endpoint.Address);
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            var msg = new TestMessage {Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()};
            Console.WriteLine("Publishing {0}", msg);
            bus.Publish(msg);
        }
    }
```

Publish queue test123, recieve queue test 345.

When I launch consumer with following code:

```
 static void Main()
    {
        var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseRabbitMq();
            sbc.UseJsonSerializer();
            sbc.EnableMessageTracing();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/test345");
            sbc.Subscribe(subs => { subs.Handler<TestMessage>(msg => { Console.WriteLine(msg.Text); }); });
        });
        bus.WriteIntrospectionToConsole();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Consumer (subscriber) handles messages and write them on console. Everything is ok on this part. But messages in test123 not acknowledged.They quantity constantly increasing, they are in ready state. They some how are consumed but doesn't go away.

What I'm doing wrong?

Another problem I can't understand is that when I delete all queues, run publisher, it creates only test345 and test345_error queues. No test123 queue. If publisher works for some time, there are few messages in test345_error and no messages in test345. When I launch consumer (see code above) it starts consume messages and it looks like to be ok. Why there is no messages in test345 queue? But somehow they are consumed (handled)?

Masstransit v2.10.0.0, RabbitMQ.Client v3.4.3.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your two programs should have different ReceveFrom() addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems to be solved by fixing both queues in publisher to be test123. No errors, no skips.